# I successfully run the telegram iOS project, but on the simulator it crashes with the error message

Tags: ios, telegram

```
objc[48964]: Class CDPCABackupRecoveryReporter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreCDPInternal.framework/CoreCDPInternal (0x16d2d7890) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreCDP.framework/CoreCDP (0x1590b2a88). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[48964]: Class CDPCAReporter is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreCDPInternal.framework/CoreCDPInternal (0x16d2d6df0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreCDP.framework/CoreCDP (0x1590b2c18). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2022-05-27 10:22:32.270742+0800 Telegram[48964:197480] [Warning] Trying to set delaysTouchesBegan to NO on a system gate gesture recognizer - this is unsupported and will have undesired side effects
Architecture: x86_64
Embedded signature, length: 8
```

On telegram-configuration I configured like this:

```
telegram_bundle_id = "ph.telegra.Telegraph"
telegram_api_id = "0"
telegram_api_hash = "0"
telegram_team_id = "0"
telegram_app_center_id = "0"
telegram_is_internal_build = "true"
telegram_is_appstore_build = "false"
telegram_appstore_id = "686449807"
telegram_app_specific_url_scheme = "tg"
telegram_aps_environment = "production"
telegram_enable_siri = False
telegram_enable_icloud = False
telegram_enable_watch = False
```

**Environment**
Xcode version: 13.3.1

MacOS version: 12.3.1

Telegram Build Version: 8.7.1

**Can anyone tell me where to configure x86_64, thank you very much**